# Disable Author Box on Homepage & on Pages

Tags: posts

I have added an Authorbox code in my entry.php between codes of post & comments.

But the authorbox is being displayed also on pages & homepages .

Any solution , to make it visible only on posts

This is code of my authorbox

```
<table style="border: solid 1px #ffffff;width:100%;">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td>
    <h3><b><span style="color: #555; ">About Author</span>&nbsp;</b>
    <input type="hidden" name="stats" value="2498">
    </h3>you can be an author too, join us and show you skills</td>
    <td style="border: solid 1px #ffffff;" align="right">
    <a href="http://mhktricks.net/user-registration/" target="_blank">
    <input class="p2graybtn" style="height: 26px; width:150px;" type="button" value="Join Us">
    </a>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    <hr>
    <table style="border: solid 1px #ffffff;">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td>

    <?php echo get_avatar( get_the_author_meta( 'user_email' ), 125 ); ?>
    </td>
    <td style="border: solid 1px #ffffff;">
    <table style="border: solid 1px #ffffff;">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td>
    <span style="color: #555;font-size:20px;font-family: Open Sans;font-weight: 400;font-style: normal;text-decoration: none;">
    <?php echo get_the_author(); ?>
    </span>
    <br><div style="margin-left:1px;">
    <?php echo get_author_role(); ?>

    <span style="position:relative;top:1px;margin-left:5px;"><img src="http://i2.wp.com/codex.iz.net/img/verified.png" height="12" width="12"></span>
    </div>
    </td>
    <td style="border: solid 1px #ffffff;">
    <div style="margin-left: 3px;margin-top: -17px;border: #B8B8B8 1px solid;border-radius:2px;padding: 0px 5px 0px 5px;font-size:10px;">
    <?php the_author_posts(); ?> POSTS</div>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table><div style="margin-top:-12px;">&nbsp;
    </div>
    <div style="margin-left:3px;margin-top:2px;padding-right:60px;">
    <?php the_author_meta( 'description' ); ?> 
<hr color="white">
<div onclick="window.open('<?php echo esc_url( get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) ) ); ?>','mywindow');" style="display: inline-block;margin-left: 3px;margin-top: 16px;border: rgb(69, 122, 234) 1px solid;background: rgb(85, 136, 244);border-radius:2px;padding: 0px 5px 0px 5px;font-size: 10px;color: white;cursor: hand;cursor: pointer;">READ MORE BY ME</div>

    <?php get_the_author(); ?>
    <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>
    </a>        
    </div>
    </td>   
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    <hr color="white">
    <hr color="white">
    <table style="border: solid 1px #ffffff;width:100%;">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td>
    <h3><b><span style="color: #555; ">Discussion</span></b></h3>
      share your knowledge.mind to help others</td>
    <td style="border: solid 1px #ffffff;" align="right">
    <a href="#" class="show-comments">
    <input class="p2graybtn" style="height: 26px;" type="button" value="Toggle Comments">
    </a>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to help when we can see your code. But here's something you can try:

```
if ( is_singular( 'post' ) ) {
    // Your author bio code
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: I added this code but it is now still their on pages & is being displayed as :http://i.imgur.com/KoRMdI4.png

Comment: It has to be inside in the PHP code within the `<?php` and `?>` tags.

Comment: after I added in these code , nothing is being displayed after title of post

Comment: I have added the code in main question , please refer to it to solve my problem

Comment: Peter, you need at least a very high-level overview of how PHP works. Try to wrap your code in `<?php if ( is_singular( 'post' ) ) { ?>` and then `<?php } ?>` at the end.